# Counting between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, date-range

I wrote a procedure which takes 3 parametes StartDate, EndDate and TimeRange. According to the TimeRange, my procedure splits dates and counting them seperately. Here is my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1] 

    @Start datetime, 
    @Finish datetime,
    @TimeRange time
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @TimeRanges as TABLE (SessionStart datetime, SessionEnd datetime);

     with TimeRanges as (
  select @Start as StartTime, @Start + @TimeRange as EndTime
  union all
  select StartTime + @TimeRange, EndTime + @TimeRange
    from TimeRanges
    where EndTime  < @Finish )
  select StartTime, EndTime, Count( Test.ScenarioID ) as TotalInboundArrivals
    from TimeRanges as TR left outer join
      dbo.Test as Test on TR.StartTime <= Test.SessionStartTime and Test.SessionCloseTime < TR.EndTime
    where Test.ScenarioID = 24  
    group by TR.StartTime, TR.EndTime   
END
```

For Example,

```
Start Time: 11:00
End Time: 12:00
TimeRange : 05:00

This procudure splits them like
     TimeRange    TotalCallPeaks
    11:00 11:05      12
    11:05 11:10      8
    11:10 11:15      15 
    etc..
```

Here is my question: I need maximum calls which happens at the same time. In other words, I need call peaks. Any suggestions or clue will be so useful for me.

[image]
There are 6 calls happened in this time range but 4 of them are happened at the same time which I want to calculate. Max point shows the max call peaks. 5th and 6th calls are happened in this time range but has no effect on the max call peaks.

Comment: A sketch of an answer - split the problem into two parts. For the first part, you want to work out the number of simultaneous calls at any interesting times - in this case the interesting times are whenever a call starts (since the number of calls just increased). For each interesting time, work out the number of active calls at that time. *Then*, for each interval, work out the max of that value that falls in that time period (also, include the latest value from before or on when that period starts).

Answer (score 0):

This should be an O(n log n) algorithm:

1. Dump all the records into a #temp table
2. Split the time range into two, run a query to see which time range has more calls

   - prune records that fall in the other half
   - keep and process both halves if the number of calls is the same across both halves. This may result in your working sets increasing from 2 to 4 etc, but may come down again for any "half" that cannot produce the same count as the others
   - if both halves contain the same records: this branch can be marked as completed. The call is simultaneous across the entire time range. You can either stop here (mark as finalized) for "one answer" or continue to find "all answers".

A draft structure of an SP that can handle this:

**TABLE: #WorkingSets**

- Partition (int) : initially left/right, then LLL/LLR/RLR etc
- session_id      : this can simultaneously appear in multiple partitions
- session_start
- session_ end
- curr_range_start
- curr_range_end   : keep halving the range between start/end
- finalized (bit)

**Variables**

- @max_calls_per_partition : locked once any "finalized" sets found

Answer (score 0):

what i've done to perform similar query is use an auxiliary table of numbers (a table with numbers 1 to 1 million for example).

look at a query like a puzzle. first, say you have your begin and end time.

12:00pm-2:00pm

cross join it to the table of numbers, now you have

```
1; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
2; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
3; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
4; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
etc...
```

next, multiply the auxiliary number by the interval you want, say 10, for example

```
10; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
20; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
30; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
40; 12:00pm; 2:00pm
etc...
```

next, add the calculated number to the begin time (in minutes if this is your interval unit) use the DATEADD function

```
10; 12:00pm; 2:00pm; 12:10
20; 12:00pm; 2:00pm; 12:20
30; 12:00pm; 2:00pm; 12:30
40; 12:00pm; 2:00pm; 12:40
etc...
```

now only grab the calculated time intervals that are between the begin time and end time, either with the where clause or your choice of inner join by a range, cross apply etc...

then, say 't1' is now your derived table from the above result set. for each row, select the number of calls that were active at that point in time, which would look like this:

select * FROM t1
cross apply (select sum(1) numcalls from yourtable t2 where t1.calculatedtimeinterval between t2.startdatetime and t2.enddatetime ) t3

Win!